# OpenGL Issue on Nexus 5 5.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I came across a problem with the Nexus 5 running Android version 5.1.1. No other device running that version has had this problem. I am using the NDK and OpenGL ES 1.1.

The problem image is the first one, where the image has some sort of interlacing issue. The second is what the image should look like. I have no idea what could be causing this. (Both images had most of the source textures smeared for testing on a cloud service.)
Can anyone tell by looking at the first image what could be going wrong? Any insight would help.

(I can't post images because I don't have enough rep!)

**Broken:** http://postimg.org/image/kuvw7esz9/

**Working:** http://postimg.org/image/b5ulyf0uz/

Edit:
I'm not doing any post-processing or anything fancy. 
Here's another image of the broken device. The interesting thing here is the dark red is the clear color, so the black should be red if it was properly rendering to the whole surface. And it's not a straight line at the bottom, it's like the stride is wrong or something.

**Another broken image** http://postimg.org/image/nrcz7wxj3/

Comment: Can you give us more precisions about what you are rendering? Are you using FBOs or any kind of post processing? What about this strange effect on the title? Is the texture like that in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the order in I was initializing gl. I never saw any initialization errors throughout this and it was very strange how it was only present on one device/OS version.

**Borked**

```
surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, NULL);

eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, 0, 0, format);
```

**Fixed**

```
eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, 0, 0, format);

surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, NULL);
```

Comment: For what it is worth I came across the exact same visual bug on the nexus 5. It looked like it was related to not having orientation information(rotating and rotating back fixed it) and moving that one line does fix it.

Comment: In addition to making it work right on the nexus 5 it also made it start working on an older Motorola that previously would just crash.  This small change is much more important than can be properly conveyed.